# flutter : expiry date text field

Tags: flutter, user-interface, dart, credit-card

how we can implement text field formatter for expire credit card date like this MM/YY

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

17 days later, but I could implement this:

```dart
class CardExpirationFormatter extends TextInputFormatter {
  @override
  TextEditingValue formatEditUpdate(
      TextEditingValue oldValue, TextEditingValue newValue) {
    final newValueString = newValue.text;
    String valueToReturn = '';

    for (int i = 0; i < newValueString.length; i++) {
      if (newValueString[i] != '/') valueToReturn += newValueString[i];
      var nonZeroIndex = i + 1;
      final contains = valueToReturn.contains(RegExp(r'\/'));
      if (nonZeroIndex % 2 == 0 &&
          nonZeroIndex != newValueString.length &&
          !(contains)) {
        valueToReturn += '/';
      }
    }
    return newValue.copyWith(
      text: valueToReturn,
      selection: TextSelection.fromPosition(
        TextPosition(offset: valueToReturn.length),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: really thanks for you , it's very useful for me

Answer (score 2):

A combination of these two formatters should produce the desired result.

```dart
class NoSpaceFormatter extends TextInputFormatter {
  @override
  TextEditingValue formatEditUpdate(
    TextEditingValue oldValue,
    TextEditingValue newValue,
  ) {
    final hasEmptySpace = newValue.text.trim() == oldValue.text;
    if (hasEmptySpace) {
      return TextEditingValue(
        text: newValue.text.trim(),
        selection: oldValue.selection,
      );
    }
    return newValue;
  }
}

class ExpiryDateFormatter extends TextInputFormatter {
  @override
  TextEditingValue formatEditUpdate(
      TextEditingValue oldValue, TextEditingValue newValue) {
    final newText = newValue.text;

    if (newText.length < oldValue.text.length) return newValue;

    var result = "";

    if (newText.contains("/")) {
      final dates = newText.split("/");
      final month = dates.first;
      final year = dates.last;
      if (year.length >= 2) {
        result = "$month/${year.substring(0, 2)}";
      } else {
        result = newText;
      }
    } else {
      if (newText.length == 2) {
        result = "$newText/";
      } else {
        result = newText;
      }
    }

    return newValue.copyWith(
      text: result,
      selection: TextSelection.fromPosition(
        TextPosition(offset: result.length),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```